# gnuplot.py - plotting time vs distance graph - multiple lines

Tags: python, gnuplot

How can I plot an x vs y graph in gnuplot.py? For example, this is what I want: http://www.mathwarehouse.com//graphs/distance-vs-time/images/distance-vs-time-graph-picture4.jpg

I want multiple lines.

My code:

```
import Gnuplot

g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(debug=1)
g.title('A simple example') # (optional)
g('set data style linespoints') # give gnuplot an arbitrary command
g.title('Data can be computed by python or gnuplot')
g.xlabel('x')
g.ylabel('y')
one = ([0, 1], [2, 3], [5, 5])
g.plot(one)
raw_input()
```

Output: http://gyazo.com/ba9fb6d6762c864758a7b494d44d384f

Only has one line. If I try to plot another, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add other data sets in you code

```
two=([6,4], [7,5], [8,3])
three=([0,2], [2,1], [5,6], [6,5], [7,7], [8,4])
```

and finally plot the three data sets by

```
g.plot(one, two, three)
```

Here is my output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions (>4.4?) of gnuplot, if you use:

```
g('set data style linespoints')
```

like in the original post, you'll get an error:

> line 0: Unrecognized option.  See 'help set'.

In stead, use:

```
g('set style data lines')
```